# How to convert List<Classname> to String array.

Tags: android, casting, typeconverter

```
public class Favoriler extends Fragment{
    List<ListViewItem> items;

    FavoriCustomLw adapter;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.favoriler, null);
        ListView cListView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.customlw);
        items  = new ArrayList<Favoriler.ListViewItem>();
        if(YabanciDiziler.contextlistposition==0){
            items.add(new ListViewItem()
            {{
                ResimKaynak = R.drawable.arrow;
                DiziIsmi = "Arrow";
                ImdbPuan = "Imdb: 9.5";
                Tur="Aksiyon";
            }});
        }


        adapter = new FavoriCustomLw(getActivity(),items);
        cListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
        });

        return v;


    }

    class ListViewItem
    {
        public int ResimKaynak;
        public String DiziIsmi;
        public String ImdbPuan;
        public String Tur;

    }

}
```

Hello I'm using custom `ListView`. I want convert `List<ListViewItem> items= new ArrayList<Favoriler.ListViewItem>();` to `String` array. I want to add converted strings to `ListView`'s `setOnItemClickListener()` method.
I want make something like this:

```
cListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(items[position].equals("Arrow")){

            }

        }
    });
```

But i can't use `items[position].equals`. How can i convert this?

Answer (score 0):

because that is not how you get it. you do this

```
items.get(position).equals("Arrow");
```

Comment: Would `"Arrow".equals(items.get(position));` help for catching nulls?

Comment: @LaughDonor is right. in get(position) returns null the app will crash for NPE, but "Arrow".equals(null) returns false, since the first check is made for instanceOf String and null instanceOf String is false